# three.js stlloader.js wireframe and select a single 'face'

Tags: three.js, stl-format

can anyone suggest how would I fix the code below to get wireframe on STL file? It will be very appreciated.p*s : Does anyone have an idea how to pick a face of loaded stl file? p*s : I just got around issue by using JSON

```
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
            loader.load('models/general_lee.stl', function (geometry) {
                geometry.scene.traverse( function(child) {
                    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                        child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x009900, wireframe: true, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );
                        child.scale.set(20,20,20)
                        scene.add( child );
                    }
                })  
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.load('models/general_lee.stl', function (geometry) {
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x009900, wireframe: true );
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  scene.add( mesh );
});
```

I think this is how you should be adding your object to the scene, though I have not tested it.
Picking faces will be the same as any other object3D object. Search google for a tutorial.

Comment: if you could help me out select codes with selecting individual face of the loaded stl file and print out its index (i.e. console.log(face[i])), I would appreciate it.

Comment: when I try to select an single face on STL object, it automatically selects the whole STL object

Answer (score 0):

After few experiments, I figured it is almost impossible to store all faces of STL file. Instead, I converted STL file to JSON using blender 2.65 converter. It works very nicely and provided me with vertices, faces, normal, even # of vertices and faces that I was able to process each faces very easily. Also, when it comes to selecting neighboring faces, I used half edge data structure.